# How to expand image if it's too tall?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well, there's my problem. I want to expand image, when user clicks the "Expand" link.
I tried CSS Clip property, but it only works with absolute positioning, and position:absolute ruins my design. Help please. Thanks in advance.
[image: Like this]

Comment: looks like at least `overflow:hidden` can help in this case :)

Comment: Agreeing with King King.  create a container with overflow hidden and then resize the container on click

Comment: Use `position:absolute`, as you say, but put it inside something that is `position:relative`.  It should no longer "ruin your design" :)

Comment: can you please showe what you tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In css you can use `overflow:hidden` and `height` or `max-height` if you wish a `transition` from unknown final `height`.

Click can be recocgnise by `:target` or `:focus` .

Here an example with target: http://jsfiddle.net/nJkwq/

```
div {
    max-height:100px;
    transition:0.5s;
    overflow:hidden;
}
a.expand, :target a.shrink {
    display:block;
}
:target a.expand, a.shrink {
    display:none;
}

div:target {
    max-height:500px;
}
```

HTML used for DEMO :

```
<div id="img" > 
    <a href="#img" class="expand"> CLICK to Expand</a>
    <a href="#" class="shrink">CLICK to Shrinl</a>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHRKp.jpg" alt="shot"/>
</div>
```